# (Co)-monads and terminating implementations

Tags: lambda-calculus, type-theory, category-theory

**The bounty above should read 'I would like to know whether the example I discuss is a com-monad and why (why not).'**

Suppose we set $\mathbb{M} \alpha := r \to \alpha$, where $r$ is some fixed type, and $\alpha$ an arbitrary type, of the STLC (Simply-Typed Lambda Calculus)

Suppose we want to define a co-monad, which contains *Co-unit* and *Co-join*, with the following types (where $\mathbb{M}$ binds more tightly than $\to$ and $\mathbb{M}$ is as stated above):

1. *Co-unit* $\;\;\;\; \mathbb{M} \alpha \to \alpha$
2. *Co-join*  $\;\;\;\;\mathbb{M}\mathbb{M} \alpha \to \mathbb{M} \alpha$

I have been told that this will not work and that we could not create a co-monad in this way, *since there is no terminating implementation for the type* $(e \to a) \to a$.

But in the pure STLC all terms are "terminating"(i.e, reductions always lead to a (unique) normal form). So I don't understand how this comment can be relevant in the case of the STLC.

Is there some link between (co)-monads and terminating implementations? Or is this just about creating a co-monad in Haskell?

Why would we not be able to construct a co-monad in the way described above?

Comment: *For any* $r$ and $\alpha$, _try_ writing down a term in Haskell/STLC of the type $(r \to \alpha) \to \alpha$. Such a term takes in a function $f : r \to \alpha$ and somehow produces a value of $\alpha$, but if you know nothing of this type you cannot produce a value of it (unless you cheat and use Haskell's `undefined`); likewise, you know nothing about $r$ and so cannot *apply* $f$ to obtain a value of $\alpha$. Hope this helps ^_^

Comment: @Musa Al-hassy But in the STLC you *can* form a term of type $(r \to \alpha) \to \alpha$. For example, $\lambda P_{r\to \alpha}. P\,j_{r}$. There is no problem with such a term in the STLC; in fact, Montague used terms of this type to interpret proper names.

Comment: What is your $j_\alpha$, is it a value of type $\alpha$? What if $\alpha$ is the empty set, then it is no longer empty.

Comment: In a STLC with an infinite stock of variables and constants of all types, you can always form a term of type $\lambda P_{r\to \alpha}.\, P\, j_{r}$.

Comment: But what is that; what does $j_r$ denote? Try to keep in mind that others are unlikely to know the particular notation you're using, unless stated explicitly. Also, then $r$ is necessarily non-empty?

Comment: What it denotes is determined by the interpretation function of the model. We just define a model so that we have an infinite stock of variables and constants of all types. Then, in the set-theoretic (Henkin) semantics, the interpretation function assigns to each constant of type $\alpha$ a member of $D_{\alpha}$ the domain of things of type $\alpha$. The variable assignment maps a variable of type $\alpha$ to a member of $D_{\alpha}$. This is outlined is the classic set-theoretic model theory of STLC.

Comment: Yes, I usually assume STLC to have the set model. Your question did not mention models and did not clearly distinguish between syntactic constructions and semantic interpretations. Okay, so you're working in a **pointed STLC**, where all types have at least one constant element. This is different than STLC, and is closer to how Haskell with `undefined` works. Now you **can** define the co-unit; check to see if the laws actually hold.

Comment: @Musa Al-hassy Not at all. I am working in Henkin's semantics for STLC.

Comment: @Musa Al-hassy This was the original semantics for the STLC, and is explained here by Henkin: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2266967?seq=3#metadata_info_tab_contents

Comment: @Musa Al-hassy The semantics is outlined in section 1.2 here https://people.ucsc.edu/~abrsvn/handout_2.pdf

Comment: I didn't know that; but I'll take a look, thanks for the link :-)

Comment: But to go back to what was said before. My point is that you surely *can* always form a term of type $(r \to \alpha) \to \alpha$, as $\lambda P_{r \to \alpha}. P \, j_r$. You then asked me "But what is that; what does $j_r$ denote". But how is that relevant to the question of whether you can form a term of type $\lambda P_{r \to \alpha}. P \, j_r$?

Comment: You can form the term, but is it then a natural transformation? Is it useful? Does it have interesting applications? Perhaps it is trivial in some sense. Also, what if you just defined the co-unit to just be constantly $j_\alpha$; does that lead anywhere intersting? I don't know; it might still be fun stuff :-) Also: You're talking about an *implementation* and indeed one cannot select constants for arbitrary types, since it may not be decidable whether they are even inhabited and, so, must rely on `undefined` which is *not terminating*.

Comment: @Musa Al-hassy In the STLC with Henkin semantics every type formed by the rules of type formation is automatically inhabited, simply because it is stated that we have constants and variables of every type. I don't see necessarily why it is trivial. $((e \to t) \to t) \to e$ could be a function which takes a set of sets and returns an an element which is in the set of sets, if there is one, and otherwise some designated element. I have found this function to be useful.

Comment: I agree with you that choice, "epsilon", functions are useful. But the problem is to try to implement (which is what is asked for) in Haskell; that is a particular interpretation of STLC in which you cannot form (arbitrary) choice functions. Anyhow, I wish you all the best!

Comment: @Musa Al-hassy that is where I think you are at the wrong end of the stick. I'm not interested in implementing it in Haskell, but implementing it in the STLC. I didn't say in my question that I was interested in implementing it in Haskell.

Comment: @Musa Al-hass With that clarified, can we form a co-monad as I described. If not, why not?

Comment: You have a term for the co-unit, now you need a term for the co-join. Form one, then check that the naturality and co-monoid conditions hold ;-)